# How to pass variables in QueryString with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to pass a variable that would represent the state of a jquery-ui accordion to the URL so I can keep the focus its current tab. I'm just unsure on how to do this since I return to a view after the POST.

Comment: why not post a value in a hidden input field? thats more natural for post

Comment: You mean you want to add a querystring parameter to the URL after you've submitted the form? Also, is this MVC or webforms?

Comment: It is MVC. And yes that's what I wanted to do. Really wasn't sure how to word it properly.

Answer (score 0):

with url in browser's address bar you can easily do this

You may try this:

http://myapp.com?param1=x&param2=y#**tab-state=second-tab**

check the cool examples [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-advanced/).